# Express + Jade: Failed to lookup view error

Tags: node.js, express, pug

So i have a directory structure as following

```
public
 views
   register.jade
```

And under my index.js file i have set up the code for template engine with Express as follow

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('register');
});
```

I have tried everything as far as the path structure but still keep getting the **failed to lookup error**

Edit: So it works when you have the views directory set out in the main path **app/views** instead of **app/public/views**. Still not understanding the underlying cause for this

Comment: Your directory structure shows `/public/view` while you are using `/public/views` in `res.render`.

Comment: @Jordonias could you pls provide further explanation

Comment: Your directory structures shows the non-plural `view` while jade is looking in plural `views`. So either use `app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/view');` or change your directory structure to `public/views/register.jade`

Comment: oh shoot thats a typo apologizes i have edited the question